# How to update an existing array with JSON objects using nodejs

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I have one array like below and let us call it as sobj

```
{
   'name':abc,
   'data':[
       [
          {'val':23}
          {'time':23}   
       ],
       [
          {'val':32}
          {'time':32}
       ]
    ]
}
```

To update this array using findAndModify method i am using below code.

```
for (var i=0; i<(sobj.length-1); i++) { //in this example, sobj.length is 2
    updateStr += '\"data.'+parseInt(i)+'\":'{val:sobj[i].val,time:sobj[i].time}+',';
}
    updateStr += '\"data.'+parseInt(i)+'\":'+type:sobj[i].type,val:sobj[i].val,time:sobj[i].time};
```

And I am trying to update the database using below code.

```
collection.findAndModify({'name':'abc'},[['_id',-1]],{$push:{updateStr}},{new:true,upsert:false},function(err,result){
            if (err) reject(err);
            else
                resolve(result);
        });
```

Though the updateStr is like below it is not updating the database when using above code. Can you let me know the correct way of processing it.

```
"data.0":[object Object],"data:1":[object Object],"data.2":[object Object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this where `sobj` is `{data:[{val:23,time:20}`,{val:23,time:20}]} and the other JSON `{'name':'abc', 'info':{[][]}}` into which I wanted to push the sobj values.

```
for (var i=0; i<(sobj.length-1); i++) {         
    updateStr += '\"info.'+i+'\":{\"val\":\"'+sobj[i].val+'\",\"time\":\"'+sobj[i].time+'\"},';         
}       
updateStr += '\"info.'+i+'\":{\"val\":\"'+sobj[i].val+'\",\"time\":\"'+sobj[i].time+'\"}}'; 


var field = {$push:JSON.parse(updateStr)};

collection.findAndModify({'name':'abc'},[['_id',-1]],field,{new:true,upsert:false},function(err,result){
            if (err) reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(result);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like there is a typo in your for loop.

You have an object named `sobj` with an array in it with the key `data`, but when you are referencing your data in your for loop you are using `sobj[i].val` and `sobj[i].time` and using the `length` of sobj.

I assume you want the data inside `data`? This would mean you will have change your code to reference the length and keys of data:

Example:

```
for (var i=0; i<(sobj.data.length-1); i++) { 
    updateStr += '\"data.'+parseInt(i)+'\":'{val:sobj.data[i].val,time:sobj.data[i].time}+',';
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, let the sobj be something like {data:[{val:23,time:20},{val:32,time:22}]} which contains two JSON objects in an array. Assume that, I have another JSON object with name and data fields in it. Value of data field is an array of arrays like data:[[{a:b}],[{e:f}],[{h:g}]] Now i want to update the data field by fetching each JSON object from sobj and store it in individual sub arrays say for example, like, data:[[{val:23,time:23},{val:34,time:34}],[{val:45,time:45}{val:67,time:67}],[{val:55,time:55}{val:44,time:44}].